# SqlCeServer: Float stores incorrectly

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, t-sql

In my debugger (VS2010), I can verify that I am sending the correct values to my **SqlCeServer 3.5 database** using an `SqlCeCommand`.

Looking at the data afterwards, I noticed that *some* of my `float` values are skewed.

- When I enter `0.006`, the database will store `0.0060000000521540642`
- When I enter `0.012`, the database will store `0.0120000001043081`
- When I enter `0.011`, the database will store `0.0109999999403954`

Other float values (1.125, 0.875, 0.75) store just fine.

Is there something special I have to do to ensure my `float` values store correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Don't use float](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html): it's *approximate*

Use fixed precision: [decimal/numeric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172424%28SQL.100%29.aspx)

Comment: OK, so I deleted my database and recreated it (that's what my app is supposed to do). This time, instead of specifying my `SqlCeParameter`'s `SqlDbType` as `Single` (which is a `float`), I used `SqlDbType.Decimal`. The data looked wrong, and when I opened up `SQL Server Management Studio`, I see that my `SqlDbType.Decimal` parameters formatted these columns as `numeric(18,0)` and rounds my values off to the nearest integer. **How do I fix this?**

Comment: @jp2code: specify p and s in `decimal(p,s)`: do not allow them to default. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceparameter.precision.aspx

Answer (score 0):

From msdn:

"not all values in the data type range can be represented exactly. "

Looks like you have found some of them!